# Scope Request in websocket

Tags: nestjs

I have a multi-tenant application with web socket that is original to use the Scope.Request for verifying the user in socket on connection, but how I can get the request for module

```js
 async handleConnection(socket: Socket) {

   const contextId = ContextIdFactory.getByRequest(???);

      const userService = await this.moduleRef.resolve(
        UsersService,
        contextId,
        { strict: false },
      );
}
```

My users service

```js
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class UsersService {
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for that case?